# Chrome DevTools - Application tab - change key in Local Storage

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

Can someone assist in following case:

I want to change language value from **"Application"** tab in **DevTools**, but got stack.

What I archived so far is, that can get value from chosen key (in **Local Storage**) - **nextLang** key

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String localStorrageValue = (String) js.executeScript("return window.localStorage.getItem('nextLang')");
System.out.println(localStorrageValue);
        if (localStorrageValue == "it") {
            JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            js1.executeScript("window.localStorage.setItem(arguments[0], argumets[i]):", "nextLang", "en");
            driver.navigate().refresh();
        }
```

Unfortunately, does not change language, as I expected (if clause)
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Expecting to change language key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found incorrect if clause query.
Here is correct one:

```
if (localStorrageValue != "en") {
        JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js1.executeScript("window.localStorage.setItem("nextLang", "en")");
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }
```